# How to intersec differents JavaPairRDD

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, java-pair-rdd

I have two different JavaPairRdd one with Key1,value and the second one with key2,value . What I try to achieve is merge them but get only the items with the same value.

I have tried the following:

```
 JavaPairRDD<String, String> finalRdd = filteredRdd.intersection(filteredsmallRdd);
```

Where filteredRdd contains key:Country , value and filteredsmallRdd contains: key:id , value . and I need which elements have the same value , with intersection i think that compare the only the key and I got an empty solution , any idea of how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `swap` to change the value as the key for each of the rdd and then perform the intersection.

```
JavaPairRDD<String,String> finalRdd = filteredRdd.mapToPair(f -> f.swap()).intersection(filteredsmallRdd.mapToPair(f -> f.swap()));
```